# Why inline-blocks are not in the same line?

Tags: html, css

So that's the markup. I have three articles in the section.

```css
* {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background: #F9FBFD;
}
article {
  width: 333px;
  height: 432px;
  background: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  /* vertical-align: top; */
}
article h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #393737;
}
article p {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #B5B7C7;
}
```

```html
<p>Our blog posts</p>
<section class="posts">
  <article>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="MSPTA">
    <h3>2021 Mid-South Parking and Transportation (MSPTA) Conference</h3>
    <p>September 21, 2021</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="PIE">
    <h3>2021 Parking Industry Expo (PIE)</h3>
    <p>September 21, 2021</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="MSPTA">
    <h3>2021 International Parking & Mobility Institute (IPMI) Conference</h3>
    <p>September 21, 2021</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

But nevertheless have the inline-block not in the same line.
[image]
**Why the second block is below?**

Comment: Because the text is one line instead of two, and all your blocks are aligned to the baseline. Bring back the commented-out `vertical-align` and you'll be all set.

Comment: Why did you comment out `vertical-align: top`? That's what you need. The default setting for `vertical-align` is `baseline`.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why inline-blocks are not in the same line is because the height of your article h3 title has different heights due to wrapping ie. 2 lines vs 1 compared to the other articles. You could uncomment the vertical-align: top;  in your example, and it would fix it but i would suggest using flex for more responsiveness. I have included an example.

```css
* {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #F9FBFD;
  ;
}

section.posts {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

article {
  flex: 3;
  background: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top; 
}

article h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #393737;
}

article p {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #B5B7C7;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Our blog posts</p>
  <section class="posts">
    <article>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="MSPTA">
      <h3>2021 Mid-South Parking and Transportation (MSPTA) Conference</h3>
      <p>September 21, 2021</p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="PIE">
      <h3>2021 Parking Industry Expo (PIE)</h3>
      <p>September 21, 2021</p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="MSPTA">
      <h3>2021 International Parking & Mobility Institute (IPMI) Conference</h3>
      <p>September 21, 2021</p>
    </article>
  </section>
</body>
```